# update to SASS files not being read,

Tags: sass

I’m having some bizarre problems using SASS. First i created some variables which reside in some files in the variables folder. i then use these variables in the main .scss file which is mysite.styles.scss
they were def working at one point.

At some point the variables stopped being read as if they weren’t defined (which they are). but even after deleting them from the mysite.styles.scss file these same error message still show, displaying line numbers on the scss file which were deleted and no longer exist. as part of troubleshooting i  even went so far as to delete everything in the file.

i’ve tried various things, running sass —watch, clearing Drupal’s cache, restarting my computer but nothing is working.

Anyone experience anything similar to this problem?

Comment: how are you compiling your sass?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with LiveReload not working. this Sass installation was used as part of the Omega theme. When i typed in drush omega-guard in the command-line it was resolved.